# Segmentation fault on manage.py cleanup

Tags: database, django, segmentation-fault

I've tried to do manage.py cleanup on my project today and it returned "Segmentation fault" no more info. I've tried setting verbose mode to 3 (-v 3), but that didn't show anyhting else.

What can be the source of the problem? Django 1.3.1, PostgreSQL 8.3 running on Ubuntu Server

**UPD**: here's last bit of a trace for `python -vv manage.py cleanup`:

```
import django.contrib.admin.models # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-

packages/django/contrib/admin/models.pyc
# trying /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/models.so
# trying /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/modelsmodule.so
# trying /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/models.py
# /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/models.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/models.py
import django.contrib.admindocs.models # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/models.pyc
# trying /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.so
# trying /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compilermodule.so
# trying /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py
# /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py
import django.db.models.sql.compiler # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Django 1.4.1, PostgreSQL 9.1, Ubuntu - works correctly

Comment: Please post the output of: python -vv manage.py cleanup ... and maybe strace ./manage.py cleanup i don't know if any of these will be useful but it could.

Comment: @HalitAlptekin it's full, unfortunately

Comment: @jpic i've added python -vv trace

Answer (score 5):

I suggest:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
python -vv manage.py cleanup
gdb python core
bt full
```

Then you will see **more crash details from python binary** and eventually can submit a bug report.